# Several plots in single pdf in R - abline cannot be drawn

Tags: r, loops, pdf, histogram

I am trying to plot many histograms in a single pdf. However, I also need to add an `abline` to each histogram. The problem is that within my loop, I need to call the `plot` function for the histogram, but I get an error if I call `plot` on an abline. How can I add it?

For example in this example:

```
pdf("plots.pdf")
for (i in 1:10){

  plot(hist(1:10))
  abline(v=2,col="red",lwd=2)

}
dev.off()
```

Comment: Change to just `hist(1:10)`, no `plot`. (By default, `hist` creates a plot.)